# Node JS express-generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-generator

I am using Ubuntu and learning Node JS. I was trying to use the express-generator that sets up a template for all the files you need to build a website. However, it locked all the folders and I can't save anything. Is this something where I have to go in and chmod every file and directory individually? Is there a better faster way? Does this happen in Windows and Mac as well?

Comment: Have you used `sudo`? "chmod every file and directory individually", no, use the `-R` flag. `sudo chown username -R directory`

Answer (score 0):

set the read/write permission to that directory or file recursively

```
sudo chmod 777 /your_project_path/

sudo chmod -R 777 /your_project_path/
```

once you set the permision then install the component in that folder

**Update**

- **755** – This set of permission is commonly used in web server. The owner has all the permissions to read, write and execute. Everyone else can only read and execute, but cannot make changes to the file.
- **777** – Everyone can read write and execute. In a web server, it is not advisable to set ‘777’ permission for your files and folders as it allows anyone to add malicious code to your server. However, in some cases, you will need to set the **777** permissions before you can upload any file to the server (For example, uploading images in WordPress)
- **644** – Only the owner can read and write. Everyone else can only read. No one can execute the file.
- **655** – Only the owner can read and write, but not execute the file. Everyone else can read and execute, but cannot modify the file.

Comment: 777 is a bit overkill, isn't it?

Comment: yeah sure, but 777 means, "let anyone do anything they want", not necessarily an advice I'd give to anyone (I also do it when I can't be bothered fine tuning, that doesn't make more OK. )

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/ check this thread

Comment: Directories : chmod 755 , Files : chmod 644 should do

Comment: change permission once you install module

Comment: your link states : "In a web server, it is not advisable to set ‘777’ permission for your files and folders"

Comment: "i had the same issue set permission work fine". That's a wrong way of solving the problem.